# Multiple y axis in jpgraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have in PHP a multi-graph realized with jpg graph: the first and the second plot have the same scale e the axis at the left, the third plot has a different scale or range of values and the axis is on the right.
With the code:

```
  $width=700;
  $height=500;

// Create the graph and set a scale.
// These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph($width, $height);

$graph->SetScale("intlin"); // X and Y axis
$graph->SetY2Scale("lin"); // Y2 axis
$theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

$graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);

$graph->xaxis->title->Set("Days");
$graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($ydata1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("#0033FF");
$p1->SetLegend('Rain');

// Create the second line
$p2 = new LinePlot($ydata2);
$graph->Add($p2);
$p2->SetColor("#33FFFF");
$p2->SetLegend('Irrigation');

// Create the third line
$p3 = new LinePlot($ydata3);
$graph->AddY2($p3);
$p3->SetColor("#000000");
$p3->SetLegend('Relative Soil Moisture');

$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(0);

// Setup a title for the graph
$graph->title->Set($titolo);
$nome_img=substr($titolo, 0, -10);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke("tmp/graph_$nome_img.png");

echo "<img src=\"tmp/graph_$nome_img.png\"> ";
```

I have only the axis to the left, right axes doesn't appear. You see the attached immage.
There is some error?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to set the margin for the graph, so see your scale. Is there, only not visible:

```
$graph->SetMargin(50,50,50,50);
```